# Products redirect to proper translation but posts don't

Tags: woocommerce, wpml

I'm using `WPML` plugin in my ecommerce site which is created using `Woocommerce`, and I prepared my site in 2 languages: default language is `fa` and second language which is `EN`. In WPML settings `language URL format` is set on `different languages in directories`.
Site's home is set as `Shop page` and everything works just fine in this page and product pages i.e. when clicking on language flags in shop catalog and single product pages, they properly open that page in that language.

The problem is on `sidebar`, where I queried last blog posts in category with `news` slug using `WP_Query`, when I click on language flags of this post to see theme in another language, i.e. when in default language the URL of other language doesn't have directory, `site.com/en/post` , and when I'm in that article in other language and click on default language flag, the URL has additional `\en\` in it, which should not have.

Could you please help me on this ?